# House rules for "critical zero"?

Tags: house-rules, fate, fudge

Rolling four blanks on 4dF yields the most-common outcome, zero, but it's one of the three most-uncommon rolls. It's exactly as unlikely as rolling a -4 or rolling a +4.

Have any of you made house-rules for something special to happen, or some special significance, of a four-blanks roll?

Answers from the Fudge point of view or from the Fate point of view are all welcome.

Comment: Questions polling for what ideas people have or have used don't really work in the Stack Exchange site format. As a rule they result in a list of ideas where [every answer is equally correct](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This question is a fine one, but doesn't fit here — you may just actually want a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack for this post.

Comment: Good advice. https://plus.google.com/111021074892106600223/posts/Sgd59Cp9ceM